# Pick and place simulation using the Robotiq 2F-140 manipulator in drake

Tags: robotics, drake

I would like to use drake to simulate pick and place with different grasp poses on meshes generated from unknown objects, because of its superb hydroelastic contact and friction modelling. I have to specifically use the Robotiq 2F-140 for this which I why I want to integrate it into drake.

I see multiple ways of doing it. My overall question would be what is the easiest?

In my GitHub [repository](https://github.com/hedaniel7/Pydrake-robotiq140), I have gathered some information about this. First, I successfully converted the official Robotiq 2F-140 .xacro file to a .urdf file in an Ubuntu 16.04 ROS Kinetic docker image. Then I successfully replaced the Schunk WSG manipulator urdf file in the [Pick and Place Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/hedaniel7/Pydrake-robotiq140/blob/master/Pick_and_Place_Robotiq140.ipynb) of Prof. Russ Tedrake (which almost perfectly sets up the pick and place scene the way I need it) with it as you can see in the following picture.

[image: Pick and Place ipynb with robotiq]

One problem hindering me to grasp with this is the 15th cell of that linked Notebook.

```
from manipulation.station import LoadScenario

X_O = {
    "initial": RigidTransform(
        RotationMatrix.MakeZRotation(np.pi / 2.0), [0, -0.6, 0.0]
    ),
    "goal": RigidTransform(RotationMatrix.MakeZRotation(np.pi), [0.5, 0, 0.0]),
}

meshcat.Delete()
builder = DiagramBuilder()

scenario_data = """
directives:
- add_directives:
    file: package://manipulation/clutter.dmd.yaml
- add_model:
    name: foam_brick
    file: package://manipulation/hydro/061_foam_brick.sdf
model_drivers:
    iiwa: !IiwaDriver
      hand_model_name: wsg
    wsg: !SchunkWsgDriver {}
"""

scenario = LoadScenario(data=scenario_data)
```

I have not written a custom controller for the Robotiq 140. I would attempt to write one if it is needed, but I suspect there might be an easier way here. I think that maybe there is already enough information in the following that I have observed about the drake repository:

1. In [Issue#19842](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/19842) "Minimal reproduction of very unstable contact forces for robotiq gripper simulation" Prof. Tedrake and user XuChenHan-TRI made it possible to grasp with the similar Robotiq 2F-85 gripper it seems, but the resulting code and models are not merged into the master and seem unavailable. I tried loading the model [here](https://github.com/hedaniel7/Pydrake-robotiq140/blob/master/Grasping-robotiq85xuchenhan.ipynb) and it couldn't find it anymore:

```
error: URI 'package://movo_description/meshes/manipulation/robotiq/visual/kinova_robotiq_coupler.obj' refers to unknown package 'movo_description'
```

2. I have observed that in the repository [models](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/models/tree/master/atlas) there are several .urdf files named robotiq. I tried loading robotiq.urdf and robotiq_simple.urdf in this [noteboook](https://github.com/hedaniel7/Pydrake-robotiq140/blob/master/Grasping-models-atlas-robotiq.ipynb), but robotiq_simple.urdf does not appear at all (which you already mentioned in [Issue#19992](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/19992)) and the robotiq.urdf returns the following mesh in Meshcat:
   [image]
3. Additionally, I want to mention Matt Corsaro's [Robotiq 3F implementation](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/compare/master...mattcorsaro1:drake:robotiq_3f_WIP) in drake here for potential reference.